# Display and Replace string from parse URL

Tags: javascript

I would like to display the parsing URL and replace string '+' with inner HTML property. Up until now, I only could do it with document.write. This is my method:

```
var getQueryString = function ( field, url ) {
  var href = url ? url : window.location.href;
  var reg = new RegExp( '[?&]' + field + '=([^&#]*)', 'i' );
  var string = reg.exec(href);
  return string ? string[1] : null;
};

var myString = getQueryString('myString');
```

Display it inside body:

```
document.write(myString);
```

The myString current result is:

"My+name+is+chka-chka+Slim+Shady"

What I would like to achieve as the result is:
"My name is chka-chka Slim Shady"

Instead of using document.write, is there any simple way to achieve the result with innerHTML?

Gracias!

EDIT: 
Thanks to Stuart I found the answer :) Here they are

Inside the `<head>`

```
var getQueryString = function ( field, url ) {
      var href = url ? url : window.location.href;
      var reg = new RegExp( '[?&]' + field + '=([^&#]*)', 'i' );
      var string = reg.exec(href);
      return string ? string[1] : null;
    };

function anyName()
    {
        var myString1 = getQueryString('your_parsedUri');
        var myString2 = myString1.replace(/\+/g, " ");
        document.getElementById('yourElementWithId').innerHTML = myString2; 
    }

    window.onload = anyName;
```

This one in the `<body>`

```
<h1><div id="yourElementWithId"></div></h1>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on where you are trying to display it (in an element with a class or id) you could use:

```
document.querySelector('.yourElement').innerHTML = myString;
```

or

```
document.getElementById('yourElementWithId').innerHTML = myString;
```

Comment: Thanks for the respond, but alas it doesn't work out yet. This is my attempt:

`<h1><script type="text/javascript">
                what();
    function what(){
document.getElementById('yourElementWithId').innerHTML = myString;
};
<div id="yourElementWithId"></div>
</script></h1>`

Comment: Not sure what you are trying to achieve with that code- its very wrong!  i took it and made a fiddle:  https://jsfiddle.net/ck0ps445/

Comment: Again, thanks a lot @Stuart. I just copy paste your code into sublime and run it with chrome Version 60.0.3112.101. It doesn't display anything and console error is "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null";

`<head>
 <script type="text/javascript">
  function what()
  {
      var myString = "something";
      document.getElementById('yourElementWithId').innerHTML = myString; 
  }
  what();
 </script>
</head>
<body>
 <h1><div id="yourElementWithId"></div></h1> 
</body>`

Comment: You likely want to add a `window.onload = what;`, as the function is executed before the DOM elements actually exist.

Comment: Thank you, it does work now. Currently it display the string "something" in DOM. But when I change `var myString = "something";` to `var myString = getQueryString('myString');` to render parsed URL as my question above. It still show `'string1+string2+string3'`. The `+` sign still show at the DOM. How to get the result `'string1 string2 string3'`? Replace the `+ ` sign with space.

BTW thanks a lot, Stuart. I learned something cool today from your answer.

Comment: You can replace the `+` with a space using:  `myString = myString.replace(/\+/g, " ");`

Comment: Wow, thank you sooo much! It does work now. You are really helpfull, Stuart. If you are nearby I'll give you croissant man. I have plenty of those at my desk.

Comment: Haha, an almond one please. Ticking the answer as correct will do for now though ;)